# solaris 10 route add on specific interface

Tags: route, solaris-10

I have 2 interfaces on Solaris box

```
# ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000 
hme0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 192.168.1.41 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether x:x:x:x:x:x
hme1: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 3
        inet 192.168.1.42 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether x:x:x:x:x:x 

# netstat -rn

Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref   Use   Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ------ ---------
192.168.1.0          192.168.1.41         U         1     91  hme0
192.168.1.0          192.168.1.42         U         1      0  hme1
224.0.0.0            192.168.1.41         U         1      0  hme0
default              192.168.1.1          UG        1     91  
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        1      0  lo0
```

hme0 the default interface but i want to specify host 192.168.1.32 to use interface hme1.
i try to use

```
route add 192.168.1.32 192.168.1.42 -interface hme1
```

but return

```
hme1: bad value
```

any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem all giving replies only applicable on Linux platform.

However on Solaris 10, the command which I found it to be work:

```
route -p <add/delete> <hostname> <gateway> -ifp <interface>
```

Answer (score 1):

[l1x's solution is correct](https://serverfault.com/questions/61906/solaris-10-route-add-on-specific-interface/61927#61927), but it has some problems; other hosts on the `hme0` side don't be able to reach `192.168.1.32`, and `192.168.1.32` might not be able to reach those other hosts.

If this is a problem, it's because your netmasks say that `192.168.1.*` is connected to *both* networks, which isn't true. Perhaps you want to do this without subnets and set the mask to `255.255.255.255` which would allow you to create routes *without* the `-interface` line.

Perhaps you can use `192.168.2.*` for one side, and route the other, although you'd need access to create the route on the router, or reconfigure all of the machines on your `192.168.1.*` network to know about this route.

If you can't do either of these things, you might be able to create a bridge.

If you're not afraid to patch your kernel and load alpha-quality drivers, you can make an [Ethernet Bridge](http://opensolaris.org/os/project/ethbridge/) (also see [RBridge](http://opensolaris.org/os/project/rbridges/)).

If an IP-only solution would be adequate, you can use proxy arp and IP forwarding to make a crude IP-only bridge. Start with something like this:

```
arp -s 192.168.1.32 macaddress-of-hme0 pub
route add 192.168.1.32 secretip
ndd -set /dev/ip ip_forawrding 1
```

Under Solaris, proxy_arp is really broken. The only reliable way to do it is to give the machine 192.168.1.32 an *additional secret IP address*, such as 10.5.3.2 that you *only* use for this.

```
,-----,         hme1,-----,   hme0
|hostA|-------------|hostB |----------- ?
`-----'             `-----'
192.168.1.32        192.168.1.41
10.5.3.2            192.168.1.42
                    10.5.3.1
```

Although, in this configuration, "hostB" doesn't require both `192.168.1.41` *and* `192.168.1.42`.

Answer (score 0):

This would the command on Solaris 10:

```
route add 192.168.1.32 192.168.1.42 -interface
```

You don't need to add the interface name after the argument -interface because the IP address 192.168.1.42 is already implicitly saying to use hme1.

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

The solaris route syntax is the follewing:

```
route [-fn] add | delete | get [net|host|default] [destination] [gateway]
```

So you command looks like this:

```
route add 192.168.1.32 -interface hme1
```

Comment: i enter the command "# route add 192.168.1.32 -interface hme1" yet i still get the error message "hme1: bad value"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
route add -net 192.168.1.0 -netmask 255.255.255.0 -interface 192.168.1.42